# Why do I get a syntax error on the testbench?

Tags: verilog

This is the testbench and throws an error at line 12 and I have no idea why. I have used many different examples and even my professors example but I do not have a clue as to why I get a syntax error for it.

```
`include "8adder.v"

module Eadder_tb; // half adder test bench
reg  A, B;   
wire sum, cout; 
E_adder add(a,b,sum,cout); 
initial 
begin 
//Dump results of the simulation to 8adder.vcd
$dumpfile("8adder.vcd");
$dumpvars;
A<= 8’b 10000001; B<= 8’b 00000111; Cin <=0;
A<= 8’b 00011001; B<= 8’b 11000000; Cin <=1;
A<= 8’b 00100001; B<= 8’b 11110000; Cin <=1;
A<= 8’b 00001111; B<= 8’b 11000101; Cin <=1;
A<= 8’b 00000001; B<= 8’b 10001110; Cin <=0;
A<= 8’b 11000001; B<= 8’b 10111000; Cin <=1;
A<= 8’b 00000001; B<= 8’b 11010000; Cin <=0;
A<= 8’b 00010001; B<= 8’b 10000010; Cin <=0;

initial 
begin 
  $monitor("time=%4d: %b + %b: cout = %b, sum = 
b\n",$time,A,B,Cin,cout,sum);   
end 
endmodule
```

The bottom code is the 8bit adder.

```
module AddEight(A, B, Cin, Cout, Sum);

output Cout;
output [7:0] Sum;
input Cin;
input [7:0] A, B;

wire c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6;

adder A0 (Sum[0], Cin, A[0], B[0], c0);
adder A1 (Sum[1], Cin, A[1], B[1], c1);
adder A2 (Sum[2], Cin, A[2], B[2], c2);
adder A3 (Sum[3], Cin, A[3], B[3], c3);
adder A4 (Sum[4], Cin, A[4], B[4], c4);
adder A5 (Sum[5], Cin, A[5], B[5], c5);
adder A6 (Sum[6], Cin, A[6], B[6], c6);
adder A7 (Sum[7], Cin, A[7], B[7], Cout);

endmodule

module adder(output Sum, input Cin, A, B);
// adder
assign Sum = A ^ B ^ Cin;
assign Cout = (A & B) | (B & Cin) | (A & Cin);

endmodule
```

Comment: I see a few syntax errors in the code youve provided. Can you please edit this question to include what the error is?

Comment: the error was that i had a syntax error, but now im getting this

eightadder_tb.v:8: warning: Port 3 (Cin) of Eadder expects 1 bits, got 8.
eightadder_tb.v:8:        : Pruning 7 high bits of the expression.
eightadder_tb.v:8: error: reg Cin; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
eightadder_tb.v:8: error: Output port expression must support continuous assignment.
eightadder_tb.v:8:      : Port 4 (Cout) of Eadder is connected to Cin
eightadder_tb.v:8: warning: Port 5 (sum) of Eadder expects 8 bits, got 1.
eightadder_tb.v:8:        : Padding 7 high bits of the port.

Comment: You have not provided the code for `E_adder` only for `AddEight` (which doesnt seem to have the same definition as `AddEight` has 5 ports; but your instantiation of `E_adder` only has 4 connections)

Answer (score 0):

`’` is not a ASCII character; it is unicode for left-apostrophe. You want to use `'` single-quote/apostrophe (no left/right distinction). I'm a little surprised you didn't have a similar issue with you double-quotes.

This issue typically happens when writing code in a word processor (apps where you write essays and emails; and have various formatting options). These applications will change ASCII single-quote/apostrophe into the unicode left/right variation because it is more appealing to the human eye when reading. You could write code in this apps, but you will need to find and disable feature that is converting the quote (also disable disable auto-uppercase and spell check while you are at it); or keep remember to hit undo command or escape key as you type.

You should to use a text editor or IDE which are more suitable for writing code. Examples in no particular order: vim, emacs, sublime, eclipse IDE, MS Notepad. These tools will not convert your ASCII input to unicode. Most of these apps will recognize and preserve common unicode characters when pasted into them. You will need to replace all the unicode directional quotes to then ascii equivalent.